# How to get service URL or data from Esri application

Tags: layers, web-service, download, url

I have website (dashboard) with Esri app including the web map (not sure what type of the service it is). I would like to use the service (or data itself) showing the gas streams in different map (either online or even better offline) so I would like to get an access to the layer.

The site with the map is accessable here: http://gulfpub-gisstg.esriemcs.com/pe-chevron-dashboard/index.html#

I am struggling to get the servise URL or data.

Comment: the highest directory is https://gulfpub-gisstg.esriemcs.com/server/rest/services/ seek permission as indicated below.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you will need to confirm if there are any useage limitations of using the layers from this application. You may need permission from the data owners / application owners.

To see the source of the data, hit F12 in your browser (or right-click -> Inspect). This opens the Developer window.

Look at the tabs and head for the "Network Tab".

Reload the page and you will see a bunch of text pop through, you will see a number of queries hitting a Map Sever.

ie:

https://gulfpub-gisstg.esriemcs.com/server/rest/services/Open_Data/World_Gas_Map_PE/MapServer/7

Which means this is the 8th layer of the World_Gas_Map_PE Map Server. Dropping back a level:

https://gulfpub-gisstg.esriemcs.com/server/rest/services/Open_Data/World_Gas_Map_PE/MapServer/

Shows some additional layers, which may or may not be present in the web map used in the Application.

Comment: Thank you, that halped me a lot!